# How can I connect Firebase DB to Django project in Python

Tags: javascript, python, django, firebase

Do you know whether it is possible to connect to the Firebase database through the Django framework in Python instead of SQL, SQLLite3, or PostgreSQL, etc.,

In the event that it is possible to connect Firebase DB to Django, can anyone please assist me in connecting Firebase DB to Django?

Comment: You can use [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) in your Python apps. Have you tried following this documentation ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your imports

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging
from firebase_admin import firestore
```

#initialize firebase en firestore database

```
json_file = //the json from firebase"
cred = credentials.Certificate(json_file)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

#initialize de database firestore

```
  db = firestore.client()
```

After this its up and running